# Extract & Expand Numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL with Microsoft SQL Server. I have a column that has values like this:

```
5-7(A-C) 15(A-C)
3(A-C)
```

I am trying to extract the numbers and if there is a dash then I need those numbers plus all the numbers in between. So for this example the output would be 5, 6, 7, 15 for the first row and 3 for the second row. I will use the results to see if they exist in another table.

I have been using this but it does not get the numbers between the dash:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('-', SUBSTRING(cc_EXPRESSION, 1, CHARINDEX('(', cc_EXPRESSION) - 1)) > 0
            THEN CAST(LEFT(SUBSTRING(cc_EXPRESSION, 1, CHARINDEX('(', cc_EXPRESSION) - 1), CHARINDEX('-', SUBSTRING(cc_EXPRESSION, 1, CHARINDEX('(', cc_EXPRESSION) - 1)) - 1) AS INT)
        ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING(cc_EXPRESSION, 1, CHARINDEX('(', cc_EXPRESSION) - 1) AS INT)
    END AS extracted_number
```

Comment: That really doesn't sound practical to do in a single query, unless you can build a function to do it or just bring the raw results out of SQL and transform the results there (say with Java, C#, Python, whatever you're using)

Comment: Thanks for the input @MPelletier. That's what I did with Python. But I thought I would ask since I don't know SQL too well and thought it might be achievable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option that illustrates how you can "stack" expressions via a CROSS APPLY and JOIN an ad-hoc tally/numbers table.

You may notice I used `TOP 1000` ... feel free to pick a more reasonable number

**Example**

```
Select A.cc_Expression
      ,NewValue = string_agg(N+R1,',')
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply string_split(cc_Expression,' ') B
 Cross Apply (values ( replace(left(B.Value,charindex('(',B.Value)-1 ),'-','.') ) )C(Rng)
 Cross Apply (values (try_convert(int,coalesce(parsename(C.Rng,2),parsename(C.Rng,1) )) ,try_convert(int,parsename(C.Rng,1) ))  ) D(R1,R2)
 Join ( Select Top 1000 N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2 )  E  on  N<=R2-R1
 Group By A.cc_Expression
```

**Results**

```
cc_Expression       NewValue
3(A-C)              3
5-7(A-C) 15(A-C)    5,6,7,15
```

Answer (score 1):

With the following table :

```
CREATE TABLE I_have_a_column_that_has_values_like_this (COL VARCHAR(256));

INSERT INTO I_have_a_column_that_has_values_like_this 
VALUES ('5-7(A-C) 15(A-C)'), ('3(A-C)');
```

You can do it like :

```
WITH 
T0 AS
(
SELECT COL, LEFT(value, CHARINDEX('(', value) -1) AS VAL
FROM   I_have_a_column_that_has_values_like_this
       CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(COL, ' ')
),
T1 AS
(
SELECT COL, CASE WHEN VAL NOT LIKE '%-%' THEN VAL + '-' + VAL ELSE VAL END AS VAL
FROM   T0
)
SELECT COL, value AS VALS
FROM   T1
       CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(CAST(LEFT(VAL, CHARINDEX('-', VAL)-1) AS INT),
                                   CAST(RIGHT(VAL, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(VAL))-1) AS INT)) AS G
```

The result will be :

```
COL                    VALS
---------------------- -----------
5-7(A-C) 15(A-C)       5
5-7(A-C) 15(A-C)       6
5-7(A-C) 15(A-C)       7
5-7(A-C) 15(A-C)       15
3(A-C)                 3
```